# How to configure Ruby on Rails with no database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It would be convenient to use Ruby on Rails for a small website project that has no current need for a database.  I know I could create an empty database in MySQL and go from there, but does anyone know a better way to run Rails without a database?

Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Uncomment this line in the `environment.rb` file:

```
config.frameworks -= [ :active_record, :active_resource, :action_mailer]
```

Comment: in rails 3 just remove the mysql gem from the Gemfile

Comment: How would you do the same in Rails 4?

Comment: Question for Rails 4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078044/disable-activerecord-for-rails-4

Comment: this is deprecated

Answer (score 121):

For **Rails 3** and **Rails 4**:

> Use `-O`(Capital 'O') or `--skip-activerecord` option to generate an application without a database.

`rails new myApp -O`

or

`rails new myApp --skip-activerecord`

This Answer is reshared from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212709/remove-activerecord-in-rails-3-beta/2212867#2212867)

---

For **Rails 5**:

> Use `--skip-active-record` option to generate an application without a database

**Notice the extra hyphen '-' as opposed to previous Rails versions**.

`rails new myApp --skip-active-record`

Comment: yes, this works with Rails 4 :) - just validated. If you want to ditch test unit use:  rails new myApp-O --skip-bundle -T

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way to go if you are starting from scratch, although be warned that (at least in Rails 4.0.1) there is a '-' between active and record in that command. So it should read: rails new myApp --skip-active-record

Comment: I just faced the issues and noticed. For Rails 4.2.x only `-O` works. The option `--skip-activerecord` does not work.

Comment: This works in rails-api too: rails new myApp -O . Thanks

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, in Rails 5 it's `--skip-active-record` (note the dash between active nad record). The other way doesn't work for me.

Comment: For rails 7 `rails new myApp -O`

Answer (score 69):

For new projects, with a simple `rails new your_app --skip-active-record` will work, but for an existing Rails 4-7 project, in your `config/application.rb` file you have the following line:

```
require 'rails/all' # or `require "rails"' in newer versions
```

(As reference that line is loading [this file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/all.rb))
So instead of load ALL, you must to load each library separately as follows:

```
# active_record is what we're not going to use it, so add it comment in case 
# at some point you enable it back again
# require "active_record/railtie" 

# This is not loaded in rails/all but inside active_record so add it if
# you want your models work as expected
require "active_model/railtie" 
# And now the rest
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie" # Only for Rails >= 4.2
require "action_cable/engine" # Only for Rails >= 5.0
require "sprockets/railtie" # Deprecated for Rails >= 7, so add it only if you're using it
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# All these depend on active_record, so they should be excluded also
# require "action_text/engine" # Only for Rails >= 6.0
# require "action_mailbox/engine" # Only for Rails >= 6.0
# require "active_storage/engine" # Only for Rails >= 5.2
```

Keep an eye to the comments to know what to load regarding your Rails version.
Also check the following files (in case you have them) and comment the following lines:

```
# package.json
"@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",

# app/javascript/packs/application.js
require("@rails/activestorage").start()

# bin/setup
system! 'bin/rails db:prepare'

# config/environments/development.rb
config.active_storage.service = :local # For Rails >= 5.2
config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

# config/environments/test.rb
config.active_storage.service = :test # For Rails >= 5.2

# config/environments/production.rb
config.active_storage.service = :local # For Rails >= 5.2
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

# spec/rails_helper.rb
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

# test/test_helper.rb
fixtures :all # In case you're using fixtures

# Only for Rails >= 5.0
#config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

Also remove any reference to `ActiveRecord::Base` in your model files (or simply delete the files if apply). For example, the autogenerated `app/models/application_record.rb` file.

Comment: For Rails 5 you might also want to require `active_job/railtie` and `action_cable/engine`

Comment: Isn't there a dummy DB adapter to use in `database.yml` so it will just ignore the DB?

Comment: Rails 5 leads then to the problem of failing `rake assets:precompile` due to `NoMethodError: undefined method `active_record'` :/

Comment: I guess also the following in `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb` should be commented: `Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
`

Comment: @Chloe The `activerecord-nulldb-adapter` from https://github.com/nulldb/nulldb allows you to swap out the adapter for a temporary or less invasive change.

Comment: This nearly worked for me in a Rails 6 project, however, the app errors out on local development initial page load and then runs fine on subsequent loads. `Puma caught this error: Cannot load database configuration:
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"] (RuntimeError)
/Users/cdm32/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:240:in \`database_configuration\'
/Users/cdm32/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:200:in `block (2 level...`

Comment: Think I figured it out, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59325729/721065

Comment: @cdmo hey, thanks for noticing. I've updated the answer to make it fully compatible with rails 6. Not sure about all you commented in your answer as I create 2 rails apps with and without `-O` and `action_mailer` isn't related with `config/detabase.yml`, so there's no need to comment it. Also there are some extra lines to comment after `active_storage` is commented.

Comment: @AlterLagos yes, you are right, ActionMailer can be enabled. I had forgotten that I removed it for a different reason in the app I am working on. Thanks for updating your canonical answer, I will remove mine 

Answer (score 17):

In Rails 4 when starting a new project you can use -O or --skip-active-record

```
rails new my_project -O
rails new my_project --skip-active-record
```

If you've already created a project you will need to comment

```
 require "active_record/railtie"
```

from config/application.rb and

```
 config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
```

from config/environments/development.rb

Answer (score 14):

If you don't need a database then you probably don't need to have the bulk of Rails. You may want a smaller more customizable framework to work with.

[Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) is a tiny framework that is great for serving up basic static pages.

But if you insist on using Rails [here](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/fr_rr/NoDatabase.pdf) is an article that will show you how to do just that or [here](http://log4p.com/2007/12/04/using-rails-without-a-database/).

Comment: Thanks - both of these links refer to the Rails Recipes book and contain steps to get testing working with a database-less rails application.

I was being lazy and hoped to leverage the rails infrastructure already on the server for other apps, but Sintatra looks intriguing.

Comment: I disagree.  Active.com is built on Rails with no database because all the data comes from an api.

Comment: Note: The second link in the last sentence no longer exists. I get a 404 not found error.

Answer (score 1):

For support Rails 6 rc1 and `activerecord-nulldb-adapter`gem we need a monkey patching

In **config/initializers/null_db_adapter_monkey_patches.rb**

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class NullDBAdapter < ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter
      def new_table_definition(table_name = nil, is_temporary = nil)
        TableDefinition.new(table_name, is_temporary)
      end
    end
  end
end
```