# Remove ActiveRecord in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Now that Rails 3 beta is out, I thought I'd have a look at rewriting an app I have just started work on in Rails 3 beta, both to get a feel for it and get a bit of a head-start. The app uses MongoDB and MongoMapper for all of its models and therefore has no need for ActiveRecord. In the previous version, I am unloading activerecord in the following way:

```
config.frameworks -= [ :active_record ]    # inside environment.rb
```

In the latest version this does not work - it just throws an error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta/lib/rails/configuration.rb:126:in
  `frameworks': config.frameworks in no longer supported. See the generated 
  config/boot.rb for steps on how to limit the frameworks that will be loaded 
  (RuntimeError)
 from *snip*
```

Of course, I have looked at the boot.rb as it suggested, but as far as I can see, there is no clue here as to how I might go about unloading AR. The reason I need to do this is because not only is it silly to be loading something I don't want, but it is complaining about its inability to make a DB connection even when I try to run a generator for a controller. This is because I've wiped `database.yml` and replaced it with connection details for MongoDB in order to use [this gist](http://gist.github.com/232953) for using database.yml for MongoDB connection details. Not sure why it needs to be able to initiate a DB connection at all just to generate a controller anyway....

Is anyone aware of the correct Rails 3 way of doing this?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

I'm going by this from reading the source, so let me know if it actually worked. :)

The `rails` command that generates the application template now has an option `-O`, which tells it to skip ActiveRecord.

If you don't feel like rerunning `rails`, you should check the following in your existing app:

- Check that your `config/application.rb` **doesn't** have `require 'rails/all'` or `require "active_record/railtie"`. Instead, for a standard Rails setup without ActiveRecord, it should have **only** the following requires:

  ```
  require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

  require "action_controller/railtie"
  require "action_mailer/railtie"
  require "active_resource/railtie"
  require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
  require "sprockets/railtie"

  # Auto-require default libraries and those for the current Rails environment. 
  Bundler.require :default, Rails.env
  ```
- If, in `config/application.rb`, you are using the `config.generators` section, make sure it doesn't have the line `g.orm :active_record`. You can set this explicitly to `nil`, if you want, but this should be the default when `g.orm` is completely omitted.
- Optional, but in your `Gemfile`, remove the `gem` line that loads the module for your database. This could be the line `gem "mysql"` for example.

Comment: Yup, that seems to have done it. It appears the -O option can also be invoked as '--skip-activerecord'. I ran the rails command for another (temporary) app with this option and it generated a new app template matching exactly what you have written above. So I could just copy and paste these changes over to my actual app. Thanks - nice find :)

Comment: Excellent - thanks for the --skip-activerecord. That's just what I needed.

Comment: That works for the most part, except when I run rails generate - I still see ActiveRecord stuff there - how do I remove it?

Comment: This trick causes the error "uninitialized constant Helper::Singleton" with Rails 3.0.5

Comment: In rails 3.1 you also need to have `require "sprockets/railtie"` in your `application.rb` file.

Comment: Just to add a quick update to this answer and my previous comment... in Rails 3.1, it is now `--skip-active-record`. Notice the extra dash.

Comment: I found the rails/all in here: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/all.rb  This way you can find out what is required from version to version.

Answer (score 46):

**Rails 4**

I was looking for how to disable it in rails 4 and only found this answer which no longer works in rails 4. So this is how you can do it in rails 4 (tested in RC1).

**In a new project**

```
rails new YourProject --skip-active-record
```

**In an existing project**

- In your Gemfile, remove the database driver gem, e.g. `gem 'sqlite3'` or `gem 'pg'`.
- In config/application.rb, replace `require 'rails/all'` with

  ```
  require "action_controller/railtie"
  require "action_mailer/railtie"
  require "sprockets/railtie"
  require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
  ```
- In config/environments/development.rb, remove or comment out `config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load`
- Potentially you have to remove active_record helpers from the spec_helper (via VenoM in the comments)
- Potentially you have to remove the ConnectionManagement middleware (seems to be the case with unicorn): `config.app_middleware.delete "ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement"` (via https://stackoverflow.com/a/18087332/764342)

I hope this helps others looking for how to disable ActiveRecord in Rails 4.

Comment: Thanks! Still you need to remove active_record helpers from the spec_helper(Not mandatory, but if you are running specs). See last comment by Rimian.

Comment: Helped me, thanks! Per the comments below, there may be other config declarations to comment out in application.rb and/or environments/{env}.rb files. YMMV.

Comment: the activerecord still remains in the gemfile.lock... Can we do something against it?

Comment: @Boti Unlikely. It's part of rails. To remove it from your .lock I imagine you'd have to remove the dependency on rails and depend on all the individual components. Check out the gemspec for the list of dependencies -- you'd want to depend on everything but activerecord. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/rails.gemspec

Comment: I seem to be running into a i18n related problem after making this change: lib/active_support/i18n.rb:13:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant I18n (NameError).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 36):

For a new rails app, you can have it exclude active record by specifying the --skip-active-record parameter.  Eg:

```
rails new appname --skip-active-record
```

Comment: I did this and ran a few diffs to find and remove the stuff in my current app that was using ActiveRecord

Answer (score 15):

If you generated a new project using Rails 3.2, you will also need to comment out:

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
```

and

```
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
```

in your **development.rb** file.

Answer (score 6):

All of the above are true. The one more thing which I had to do in rails 3.1 is to comment out

```
config.active_record.identity_map = true
```

in `config/application.rb`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running rspec, you also need to remove (in spec_helper):

```
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
```

and remove

```
  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Also **comment** out

```
# config/application.rb    
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

(noted on rails 3.2.13)