# Rails 3 - how do I avoid database altogether?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use rails 3 without any db backend, but it still insists on requiring 'sqlite3' gem when I try to access a page, and throws an error `no such file to load -- sqlite3`, even though no code in the application requires sqlite, except I left database.yml with its default setting for sqlite3, since removing the content raised other errors. Any idea how I could use rails without any database and avoid said errors? thanks.

(also, I'm familiar with Sinatra - just prefer rails for this project).

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Rails 3:

In `application.rb`, remove the `require 'rails/all'` line and instead add these lines:

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

Also see [Remove ActiveRecord in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212709/remove-activerecord-in-rails-3-beta)
and look into the [Active Model](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model) railscast

Rails 3.2.x:

You'll also need to remove/comment out this line in application.rb

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

And remove/comment these two lines from development.rb

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
```

Rails 2.x:

In `config/environment.rb` add (or uncomment) the line

```
config.frameworks -= [ :active_record, :active_resource, :action_mailer ]
```

This will cause Rails not to use those frameworks. (Note the nearly-invisible `-=` !)

Comment: I think this works in rails 2.x - I get a deprecation message and an error in r3.

Comment: Updated the answer with the method used in Rails 3

Comment: In Rails 3.1 and 3.2 you need to also follow the advice in Rod's answer, which is to remove all references to `config.activerecord` in the config/environments files.

Comment: In the end I didn't need the `config.frameworks -= [ :active_record, :active_resource, :action_mailer ]`.  I'm on 3.2.13, and it seemed to work out just fine if I did the rest of these changes and Rod's as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Also, in Rails 3, remove any references to active_record in

config/environments/development.rb

config/environments/test.rb and

config/environments/production.rb such as

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
```

as well as removing require "rails/all" and adding the require lines in comment 21 (above).

if you are not using a database (this works with Rails 3.1.1)