# Rails 3.1: Cucumber test without a database

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cucumber

I have a simple Rails 3.1 application that doesn’t have any database. But when I executes Cucumber tests all test scenarios were failed due to the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
```

It would be helpful, if I get a solution to resolve this BDD issue.

Answer (score 2):

With the gems below, I've got cucumber working with Rails 3.1 and no database.  The only things I modified were

In application.rb, remove the require 'rails/all' line and instead add these lines:

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

remove references to DatabaseCleaner in the features/support/env.rb file

Gem versions:

```
actionmailer (3.1.1)
actionpack (3.1.1)
activemodel (3.1.1)
activerecord (3.1.1)
activeresource (3.1.1)
activesupport (3.1.1)
ansi (1.4.1)
arel (2.2.1)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21)
capybara (1.1.2)
childprocess (0.2.3)
coffee-rails (3.1.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.1.3, 1.1.2)
cucumber (1.1.3)
cucumber-rails (1.2.0)
database_cleaner (0.7.0)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.2.9, 1.2.6)
ffi (1.0.11)
gherkin (2.6.8)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
jquery-rails (1.0.19, 1.0.14)
json (1.6.2, 1.6.1, 1.6.0)
mail (2.3.0)
mime-types (1.17.2)
multi_json (1.0.4, 1.0.3)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.3, 0.3.2)
rack (1.3.5, 1.3.3)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.1.1, 3.1.0)
railties (3.1.1, 3.1.0)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.11, 3.9.4)
rubyzip (0.9.5)
sass (3.1.11, 3.1.7)
sass-rails (3.1.5, 3.1.2)
selenium-webdriver (2.14.0)
sprockets (2.0.3, 2.0.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.4)
term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
turn (0.8.3)
tzinfo (0.3.31, 0.3.30, 0.3.29)
uglifier (1.1.0, 1.0.3)
xpath (0.1.4)
```

I used this SO question: [Rails 3 - how do I avoid database altogether?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954307/rails-3-how-do-i-avoid-database-altogether)

Comment: This did work for me with and extra step: I had to remove the database_cleaner gem from my gemfile.