# Rails - disable db connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There's a Rails 3.2.3 web application which doesn't use any database. But in spite of that if I use the `gem 'sqllite3'` in `GemFile` I works perfect. But if I use `gem 'pg'` in that file it throws an error

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

Of course, I use different versions of `database.yml` when I use `postgreSql` or `SqlLite3`.

But I definitely don't use any database.

Why is it happening? What should I do to solve it? And how to disable using databases?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3 - how do I avoid database altogether?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954307/rails-3-how-do-i-avoid-database-altogether)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954307/rails-3-how-do-i-avoid-database-altogether) for how to bypass using a database. It's a little more work than just setting a flag.