# Rails application without any database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Can we start (or) run a rails application without any database?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the beginning of your `config/application.rb` file you should have something like this:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
#require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

When you remove this line:

```
require "active_record/railtie"
```

`ActiveRecord` will be gone and your app won't require a database connection.

You can also create the project with `--skip-activerecord` if it's a new one.

Answer (score -1):

Check this link [Rails 3 - how do I avoid database altogether?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954307/rails-3-how-do-i-avoid-database-altogether).

You just need to make sure in configuration that the database related classes are not in use. There might be more help on web.

Comment: Though @Linhares answered in a very brief and clear way, I think this link provides more comprehensive answer to this question. However, thnx :)