# How do I remove the dependency for sqlite3 in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, sqlite

I'm trying to create a work-around for a Rails app that disables the dependency for sqlite3 (and databases in general). Are there any efficient methods?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212709/remove-activerecord-in-rails-3.

Comment: @toro2k, is there a setup for Rails 4? The active_resource railtie returns a LoadError.

Answer (score 1):

`rails new myApp --skip-activerecord`

Check "[Rails 3 - how do I avoid database altogether?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954307/rails-3-how-do-i-avoid-database-altogether)" for more info.

Comment: Use descriptive text when creating anchor text, don't use "this" or equally undescriptive phrases like "click here". Give the reader a clue what they are about to click-on. See the "Don't use 'click here' as link text" 
 http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere.

Comment: Awesome! How about for Rails 4? Same as Rails 3? Also, and I may be wrong about this, but can't I just use the command `rails new -o myApp` to skip ActiveRecord configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out! @Vimsha was close; turns out its actually `rails new app --skip-active-record`! :P