# Rails Controller Without Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, server-sent-events

I am building a Rails service that uses [Server-Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events) (**SSE**) to stream events to the browser. There is a controller with standard RESTful endpoints for manipulating / querying data, and then another controller (inheriting from `ActionController::Live`) that handles the asynchronous code. Then, in the middle I have Redis as a pubsub

Because I am pre-computing the messages I'd like to send in the RESTful controller, I do not use the database in the SSE controller (the auth does not require a database connection).

**The Problem:**

Because the database connection is being unnecessarily grabbed from the pool, I am limited in the number of connections, but the number of database connections I allow.

**Question:**

Is there a way to `skip_before_filter` (or similar) to avoid requiring a database connection?

Comment: There shouldn't be a reason why a controller would create a database connection. That is a models responsibility. Can you please post your controller?

Comment: No, there is no user authentication being done (in the traditional sense at least). Instead we're just using a signed token, and we don't need to check if that user exists in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable db connections by default. I think this SO post tells you how:

[Rails 3 - how do I avoid database altogether?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954307/rails-3-how-do-i-avoid-database-altogether)