# Lightweight Ruby MVC web development framework which plays nicely with ExtJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, frameworks, extjs

I'm looking for a lightweight MVC Ruby framework for developing an ExtJS application.
I started with Rails 3.0, but I feel that I'm struggling with the ActionPack (which I don't really need).

Since all the UI (view) is done in ExtJS, I don't need any rendering support. What I do need is a routing infrastructure (for REST), session support and something like "devise" plugin, so I won't need to reinvent the wheel with regard to registration, authentication, notifications and so on.

Sinatra feels too bare-bones, and I didn't quite succeed with Ramaze, but willing to give it another try.

Now, there're some new kids around the block, like padrino, but I think that they are missing the authentication part.

I hoped that after the Rails/Merb merge it'll be possible and easy to cherry pick the needed features, but either this is not yet implemented, or poorly documented.
So I'm looking for either another framework, or some way to ditch the ActionPack (or most parts of it) - links are welcomed.

P.S. I'm ORM agnostic, but will probably go with ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

You can use config.frameworks -= [...]   option, in the environment.rb file,  to remove all parts of the framework you're not going to use.
For example:

```
config.frameworks -= [ :active_record, :active_resource, :action_mailer ]
```

Comment: It no longer works with Rails 3.0.x :( There's another thread which talks about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212709/remove-activerecord-in-rails-3-beta , but it doesn't provide any means to get rid of actionpack...