# Rails asset pipeline not working in production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have recently upgraded an app from Rails 3.0 to 3.1. I have followed any instructions I could find for enabling the asset pipeline but it always fails when in the **production** environment:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

gives me

```
<script src="/javascripts/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which is missing a digest and I get the following error:

```
cache: [GET /javascripts/application.js] miss
Started GET "/javascripts/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-03 23:31:36 +0100
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/application.js"):
```

I've tried variations of these settings in application.rb:

```rb
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

#require 'rails/all'
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end


module Blog
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

and full production.rb (minus some comments)

```rb
Blog::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

I have ran the `rake assets:precompile` task.

Am I missing any obvious steps?

**Edit:** Some additional details:

My assets are in `app/assets` folder. `app/assets/images`, `app/assets/javascripts`, `app/assets/stylesheets`, etc.

I see my files generated in my `public/assets` directory with names and digests.

`app/assets/javascripts/application.js` does indeed compile to something like `public/assets/application-6ec417a53cb2bdb949966a153a61e7b1.js` They end up in the `public` directory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sprockets is not getting loaded.

In an effort to remove active record in a previous version of rails (a la this question [Remove ActiveRecord in Rails 3 (beta)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212709/remove-activerecord-in-rails-3-beta/2212867#2212867)) the `require 'rails/all'` was replaced by

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

What was missing here was `sprockets/railtie`

Comment: I was using RSpec, and therefore had a similar setup with test_unit commented out. I had no idea sprockets had its own railtie. Thank you so much for this.

Answer (score 3):

See the [Upgrading to Rails 3.1 Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1)

Make sure your assets are in `app/assets` folder. `app/assets/images`, `app/assets/javascripts`, `app/assets/stylesheets`, etc.

Execute `rake assets:precompile`

You should see files generated in your `app/public/assets` directory with names and digests if enabled.

`app/assets/javascripts/application.js` would compile to `/assets/application-6ec417a53cb2bdb949966a153a61e7b1.js`

If the asset is named similar to above with a digest, `Production.rb` should have the following config:

```
# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

If you look at the web page source you should see something similar to the following:

```
<script src="/assets/application-6ec417a53cb2bdb949966a153a61e7b1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Try to manually load the file by going to `http://example.com//assets/application-6ec417a53cb2bdb949966a153a61e7b1.js`

The file should load, if not try checking permissions and further logs.

Comment: Thanks, I had watched the rails cast when making my changes. I have update my answer to address your suggestions.

Comment: Can you post your `application.rb` and `production.rb`?

Comment: I have added full `application.rb` and `production.rb` to the question. Full repo: https://github.com/trevorpower/trevorpower-com