# disabling direct SQL queries in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We are running a rails+mysql application. In my specific requirement I want all my developers to access mysql only throught the rails API. I want to disable all direct mysql queries outside ActiveRecord.

This is because we run a lot of callbacks at activerecord to maintain integrity of data.

How to implement this?

Comment: I think following link would help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212709/remove-activerecord-in-rails-3.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the above link has to do with my question??

Comment: ok....sorry I misunderstood your question.
what you want to do is use active record query instead of mysql query?

Comment: Yes. And even if someone uses my mistake I should have some way to prevent it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to implement this?

Code reviews.

You're not going to prevent "direct mysql queries outside ActiveRecord", because you can do direct SQL queries with ActiveRecord:

```
Model.find_by_sql("DELETE * FROM admin_table")
```

Your best approach will probably be to ensure that the code your developers are writing is following the best-practices you determine. Do this by peer-review processes and education.