# Site runs on heroku, ActiveRecord error locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my first site on Heroku. I got everything setup and the stuff I've pushed to Heroku runs fine. However when I run foreman to test locally I get:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

The full trace is:

```
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__106420346196994475__call__674805951980893958__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm new to rails and heroku and can't figure this out. The site is very basic. No db, just a simple html page with a navbar from twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Rails will create connection to Database. There are several ways of removing that connection (by removing ActiveRecord from Rails).

If you are creating new Rails project you can use  --skip-activerecord command to disable ActiveRecord. If you wanna to convert already created project you must manually reconfigure it. More info on http://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/running-rails-3-with-no-activerecord

Regarding Heroku, it works because Heroku injects database connection to you project.

Comment: I tried that however foreman crashes if I do it. invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) (SyntaxError)

Comment: I successfully removed AR from my project. Try this for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212709/remove-activerecord-in-rails-3