# tell bundler to ignore certain dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, rails-activerecord

I have a rails 2 app that I'm upgrading to use bundler. Unfortunately, this app does not use active_record (but uses every other component of rails heavily).

Previously, to have the app ignore active_record I had the following in my environment.rb file:

```
config.frameworks -= [ :active_record ]
```

However, it seems that bundler is forcing active_record to load which obviously throws errors since there isn't a database specified.

I'm using rails 2.3.16 (actually attempting to upgrade to it as part of this process).

I've searched around a bit, and the closest I have found was this open ticket:

https://github.com/wycats/bundler/issues/143

Is my only option to explicitly modify the Gemfile.lock and remove all references to active_record?

Answer (score 0):

- Check that your `config/application.rb` **doesn't** have `require 'rails/all'` or `require "active_record/railtie"`. Instead, for a standard Rails setup without ActiveRecord, it should have **only** the following requires:

  ```
  require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

  require "action_controller/railtie"
  require "action_mailer/railtie"
  require "active_resource/railtie"
  require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
  require "sprockets/railtie"

  # Auto-require default libraries and those for the current Rails environment. 
  Bundler.require :default, Rails.env
  ```
- If, in `config/application.rb`, you are using the `config.generators` section, make sure it doesn't have the line `g.orm :active_record`. You can set this explicitly to `nil`, if you want, but this should be the default when `g.orm` is completely omitted.
- Optional, but in your `Gemfile`, remove the `gem` line that loads the module for your database. This could be the line `gem "mysql"` for example.

(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212709/remove-activerecord-in-rails-3))

Comment: I'm on Rails 2.3.16, so there isn't a application.rb file I can modify.

I tried removing the gem 'mysql' line as well, but that didn't help.

Comment: Spoke too soon...forgot to run 'bundle update' when I removed mysql. That seems to have fixed it...thanks!

I'll post back if I run into additional trouble.