# rails : how can i integerate expedia api to sample app with no database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i would like to know how to integerate expedia api in a sample app with zero database such that it should have a functionality to improve search function and enable anyone to pull from the Expedia to provide a comprehensive search based on the keyword entered like in the link

-something  similar to www.helloweekends.com. When you run a search on their site, the results in the dropdown are broken down into three sections. how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a gem [expedia](https://github.com/zaidakram/expedia) which will help you a lot

Answer (score 1):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212709/remove-activerecord-in-rails-3) will help with the first part of your question (a rails app with no activerecord)

You could have a search method that uses an http library like [HTTParty](http://rubygems.org/gems/httparty) to take the input from your user, make the same call to other services, get the the results, and aggregate them in your search method as you see fit.