# Rails Application without Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Here I want to develop online chat application in Rails but without database so, I thought of using sessions instead.

Coming to application users will come to home page and click join chat button after that by filling two fields (like Name and Gender) his record should create in session.

after chat by closing his record should automatically destroy.

Is there any sample work-arround or example for this kind of application online?

Answer (score 1):

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/821269/382982 will help you remove Rails' default database dependency. Sessions *should* still work normally (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session).

Comment: Thanks for the answer ethagnawl!! I want to use sessions like Activerecord. lets say user wants to find other online users by name or location etc., I need to achieve all without database. all current user details I need to store in sessions and retrieve from them.

Comment: While I can't say for certain, I don't think that's possible... My understanding is that Rails sets the session in a cookie, passes that back to the user and then whatever data is contained in it falls out of scope. Have you considered using Redis or Memcache?