# Disable ActiveRecord for Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to disable ActiveRecord in Rails 4. I did the following in `config/application.rb`

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# require 'rails/all'  -- commented

require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
#require "active_resource/railtie" no need
#require "rails/test_unit/railtie" no need
#require "sprockets/railtie" no need

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
     config.app_middleware.delete "ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement"
  end
end
```

By I have an error of

```
/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in 
  method_missing: undefined method active_record for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000002005c38> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Why not just use `rails new ... -O` to disable activerecord?

Comment: Is the app_middleware.delete needed, might even be causing the issue?

Comment: For existing rails 4/5/6 apps, you could disable active record [following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26065959/895789).

Answer (score 274, accepted):

If you are creating a new application, you can use `-O` to skip ActiveRecord:

```
rails new my_app -O
```

For existing applications:

**1. Remove database adapter gems from your Gemfile (mysql2, sqlite3, etc.)**

**2. Change your `config/application.rb`**

Remove `require 'rails/all` line and require frameworks (among those [available](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.2.2/railties/lib/rails/all.rb) in your `rails` version, the list varies, do not just copy) you want to use, for example:

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Remove `config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true` from `config/application.rb`

**3. Delete your `config/database.yml` file, `db/schema.rb` and migrations (if any)**

**4. Delete migration check in `test/test_helper.rb`**

**5. Delete any ActiveRecord configuration from your `config/environments` files (this is what is causing your error)**

This is all you need to do for an empty Rails app. If you run into problems caused by your existing code, stack trace should give you sufficient information on what you need to change. You might for example have some ActiveRecord configuration in your initializers.

Comment: In addition to these changes, I also had to remove a couple of lines from spec_helpers.rb (using RSpec): about fixtures and transactions.

I was also using active_model, so I replaced active_record with active_model in the requires list from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078044/disable-activerecord-for-rails-4

Comment: Where can I see a list of the available Rails frameworks, to be required in lieu of 'rails/all'?

Comment: The list of everything `require 'rails/all'` includes can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/all.rb).

Comment: I created an application with `rails new my_app -O` a month ago. Now I  want the active record back. What are files/gems/configuration I need to add now?

Comment: This is really handy, thanks. Although I also found it helpful to include `require 'active_model'` in application.rb (I'm using the validations from ActiveModel, but not the db interactions from ActiveRecord).

Comment: I also had to remove `config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true` from `config/application.rb`.

Comment: Works in Rails 5.1.4 as well.

Comment: Doing this in Rails 6 I found I needed to do as in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/60041361/8940624

Comment: What are "migration check in test/test_helper.rb", might I ask?

Answer (score 16):

Hi this is what the default rails new new_app -O gives

```
require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want: 
require "active_model/railtie" 
require "active_job/railtie"
# require "active_record/railtie" 
require "action_controller/railtie" 
require "action_mailer/railtie" 
require "action_view/railtie" 
require "sprockets/railtie" 
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

inside your **config/application.rb**

Additionally, it comes without **database.yml** and NO **db/migrate/*** and **schema.rb**

Comment: and for rails 5 <= add `require "action_cable/engine"`

Answer (score 8):

Since this is still the first hit when searching Google for disabling active record for Rails 5, I'll add this here:

**For Rails 5**

Do all the steps in @mechanicalfish answer, but also remove the line

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

from

```
config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb
```

Answer (score 5):

For those using the [rails-api gem](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) you may encounter a similar error when using the `--skip-active-record` flag when doing `rails-api new my_api`. The current fix (until a new corrected version of the gem is released) is to edit your rails-api gem to have [this commit](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/commit/62cbe9fde403822c40fb31d0bd897c608f104d51). Use `bundle open` and replace the old `Gemfile` with the new corrected one. Rerun and you should be all set.

Answer (score 4):

For disable ActiveRecord in Rails 4.2 you may create **config/initializers/middleware.rb**

```
Rails.application.middleware.tap do |middleware|
  middleware.delete ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending
  middleware.delete ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
  middleware.delete ActiveRecord::QueryCache
end
```

See the terminal **rake middleware**

Answer (score 4):

## For Rails 5:

**If you are generating a new app**

Use `--skip-active-record` option to generate an application without a database:

`rails new myApp --skip-active-record`

> Notice the extra hyphen '-' as opposed to previous versions of Rails.

Comment: In case you have already created your project without skipping active record,
Just comment all active_record references in config/environments/

# config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true
# config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

And rename your database.yml file to something else.
That did it for me.

Comment: also comment this line in bin/setup =>  # system! 'bin/rails db:setup'

Answer (score 1):

**For Rails Plugins (or gems) with a `spec/dummy` app**

When your rails app lives in `spec/dummy` and you start your server from the plugin-root directory. You might still getting following error:

```
Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`: Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]
```

To avoid this, remove `require rails/all` inside the file `bin/rails` and require frameworks you want to use, for example:

```
# Pick the frameworks you want: 
require "active_model/railtie" 
require "active_job/railtie"
# require "active_record/railtie" 
require "action_cable/engine"
require "action_controller/railtie" 
require "action_mailer/railtie" 
require "action_view/railtie" 
require "sprockets/railtie" 
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Answer (score -1):

For Ruby On Rails version 5.1.x

```
require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
# require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```