# Change Database Adapter for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, couchdb

I'm trying to create a rails 4.0 app using CouchDB both locally and deployed on heroku.  I have CouchDB installed and running locally and the Cloudant addon for heroku.  Heroku complains that `DATABASE_URL` is invalid at the `rake assets:precompile`step.  When I run this locally (as well as when I run `rails server`) I get the obvious error:

> Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded

However, I don't want to use `sqlite3`, I want to use CouchDB.  For lack of a better known option, I'm using the [`couchrest_model`](https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest_model) gem, and I have it in my Gemfile as `gem 'couchrest_model'`.  Their README goes on to say,

> CouchRest Model is configured to work out the box with no configuration as long as your CouchDB instance is running on the default port (5984) on localhost.

I can understand why it wouldn't work with Heroku since I may need additional configuration (although I'm not sure what that would be -- I assume Heroku takes care of that automatically), but CouchDB *is* running on localhost:5984 on my own machine.

I have noticed that `config/database.yml` has references to `sqlite3` for development/test/production.  If I comment these out, I get complaints not specifying any connection adapter.

What do I have to do to at least get the app running with CouchDB locally and ideally with Heroku as well?

Comment: According to [this](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=CouchDB), there isn't a definite couchdb adapter gem you can use. I would try the most popular one, but it looks outdated.

Comment: @dmtri.com I'm really not familiar with rails ... what exactly are you suggesting that I do?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a `config/couchdb.yml` and set up your configuration something like below (check out [Configuration section on the couchrest_model documentation](https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest_model#configuration)

```
development:
  protocol: 'http'
  host: localhost
  port: 5984
  prefix: project
  suffix: development
  username: test
  password: user
```

and for heroku, you might want to specify the Cloudant host

```
production:
  protocol: 'https'
  host: sample.cloudant.com
  port: 5984
  prefix: project
  suffix: test
  username: production
  password: user
```

Something like that

Also, you need to get rid of Active Record

In `config/application.rb`, delete `require rails/all` and replace it with

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

In `config/environments/development.rb`, comment out

```
# config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
```

And then you should be able to delete `config/database.yml` and remove `sqlite3` gem without getting Active Record errors

Check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078044/disable-activerecord-for-rails-4) about disabling active record for rails 4 as well

Comment: I've already added the `config/couchdb.yml` as specified in my question.  It doesn't fix the issue

Comment: And you should remove Active Record, I just edited the question and added that, hope that helps