# running a simple rails-api project returns ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

This might be a really stupid question. But I am starting to create a rails API and created a skeleton api with one controller index action which returns a static json.

Here is the sequence of steps I followed:

```
rails-api new my-app
```

My gemfile has:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
```

My routes are as follows:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :projects
    end
  end
end
```

here is my controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

      def index
        render json: {message: 'Resource not found'}, status: 404
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my model which has nothing:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

So when I try run the app rails s and go to:

```
localhost:3000/certificates/ or localhost:3000/api/v1/certificates
```

I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

Eventually I am going to add a database and retrieve results from a real table, but I was wondering shouldn't my above code return the json "Resource not found" instead of trying to connect to active record.

Does it always require an activerecord connection? I am trying to understand how rails-api works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the server `ActiveRecord` gets loaded automatically, and it will whine since it wants a db to connect to. Ìf you really need to, you can "deactivate" `ActiveRecord` on startup by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078044/disable-activerecord-for-rails-4).