# Activerecord not removed from Gemfile.lock even after removing gem from Gemfile (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I made a new project and by default I got `sqlite3` in my `gemfile`. I did some work in the project, but now I want to install the `mongoid` gem. I already have `mongodb` setup in my system.

I used [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319002/how-do-i-remove-activerecord-from-an-existing-rails-4-application) to remove `ActiveRecord`. I removed `sqlite3` and added 'gem mongoid' in `gemfile`. I ran `bundle install`. However, even though I have removed `sqlite`, `ActiveRecord` still persists in `gemfile.lock`.

**How can I remove `ActiveRecord` and all other related dependencies from my `gemfile.lock`?**

**Update** - This is a small project. What if someone have to switch from `ActiveRecord` to `Mongoid` in a big, live project? How could a person migrate in such a scenario?

Comment: Delete your Gemfile.lock file and again run bundle install. This must help. If this doesn't help there is another possibility that any other gem you have installed requires activerecord gem.

Comment: I cannot delete my gemfile in this (rails 5) project, even through terminal and I also checked rails itself have dependency on activerecord.

Comment: What do you mean you can't remove it? `rm Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: I used the commoad but file regenerates itself. I even used 'rm -r Gemfile.lock'. I am able to delete the file in rails 4 project but not in rails 5 project.

Comment: This file is generated only after you run bundle install. I'm also using rails 5 but I can delete the file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove the `activerecord` gem to switch ORM's to Mongoid. Which is actually not possible since its a dependency of Rails.

To remove ActiveRecord from the application:

### 1. Get rid of the railtie.

Railties are how you load parts of the framework in rails.

```
# config/application.rb
require_relative 'boot'

require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
# require "active_record/railtie" -- remove or comment this line!
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

This means that the `active_record` gem will no longer be required and loaded into memory.

### 2. Clean up the configuration

When you generate a new rails app your config has quite a few ActiveRecord specific options. So use `grep` or the search option in your favorite editor to remove any lines containing and remove all lines containing `config.active_record` from `config/environments/*.yml`.

### 3. Remove cruft

You can then get rid of the following files/folders:

- `/config/database.yml`
- `/db/schema.rb`
- `/db/migrate`

> Update - This is a small project what if someone have to switch from
>   active record to mongoid in a live and big project. How will a person
>   can migrate in such a scenario?

Switching ORMs in a mature project is pretty rare as it will require extensive rebuilding. But you would follow the steps above or run Mongoid and ActiveRecord in parallel until the conversion is complete. This is hardly something you would do live - it is most like a long running major version project.

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible if you have another gem in `Gemfile` which have dependency on `activerecord`. In your case it's `rails` so you can just leave it here.

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    ...
    rails (4.2.5.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.5.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.5.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.5.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.5.1)
      activerecord (= 4.2.5.1)
```