# Disable ActiveRecord in Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am a newbie in Rails.

I want to disable ActiveRecord in Rails 5.

I've already found several answers 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319002/how-do-i-remove-activerecord-from-an-existing-rails-4-application), [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821251/how-to-configure-ruby-on-rails-with-no-database) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078044/disable-activerecord-for-rails-4)

But none of them seems working for me.

Would you help me with this issue, please?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you say they ain't working? is it an existing app/new app? what is the error you are getting?

Comment: It's an existing app and I get this error. NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord.

Comment: see..that means you have got rid of `AR` and so your app can't find it. Now, which line throws that error? any backtrace?

Comment: It doesn't give any line on my source project. It says lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:550 and it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accepted answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078044/disable-activerecord-for-rails-4) of [mechanicalfish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1464605/mechanicalfish) is right.

But in my case, I've done following 2 additional things (I've used Rails 5.1.2)

**Delete model files** in models directory

models/application_record.rb

models/widget.rb

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works for me. But I couldn't find widget.rb file.

Answer (score 4):

Just to update, there is no need to delete anything by hand if you are using Rails 5 or greater.

For new rails application in Rails version 5 or newer, all of these are handled. Just run the rails new command with `-O` (`--skip-active-record`) argument.

```
> rails new proj_no_db -O
```

For api only Rails application without DB,

```
> rails new proj_api_no_db -O --api
```

Answer (score 2):

Just comment database in database.yml and it will be working. Tested in rails 5.2

```
 username: root
 password: anyPass
 #database: db_name
```