# Disabling ActiveRecord in Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I used the [Disable ActiveRecord in Ruby on Rails 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008990/disable-activerecord-in-ruby-on-rails-5) as a reference, but my problem was not solved.

I'm experiencing the problem below

```
Cannot load database configuration:
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"] (RuntimeError)
```

Do you know what to do?

Comment: Are you converting an existing project or creating a new one?

Comment: try following this steps https://revelry.co/rails-app-without-database/

Comment: I am working on an existing project

Answer (score 0):

If you creating new project then you can exclude ActiveRecord by running the command: 
`rails new yourprojectname -O`
where the -O param is used for not including ActiveRecord into newly created project.

For existing project please check this advise here: [How do I remove ActiveRecord from an existing Rails 4 Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319002/how-do-i-remove-activerecord-from-an-existing-rails-4-application)

For Rails 5 there is one more suggestion to do:
Do all the steps from link above, but also remove the line

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

from

```
config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb
```

Comment: Thank you
Everything was done.
Still, I get the same error