# Rails without ActiveRecord - tidying up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Okay, I've been experimenting with one of my apps, which doens't need data persistence between environment loads and only has a very small dataset.

I've managed to replace ActiveRecord in all of my models, I've even removed my db directory, and it has sped up the app ten-fold. However, there's a couple of parts I can't seem to get rid of...

- The rake tasks which refer to db (`rake db:migrate` etc.)
- the activerecord gem (which is loaded by bundler as a dependency to rails)

Also is there any more fat I can trim from my app now I'm not using any AR?

Comment: You can remove the ActiveRecord railtie: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078044/disable-activerecord-for-rails-4

Comment: The question suggested as a duplicate solved my problem. Does anyone know if I should delete this one, mark it answered etc.?