# How to use rails generators without active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel, rails-generate

I am building a rails app without a database.
In [Disable ActiveRecord for Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078044/disable-activerecord-for-rails-4) I learned how to configure the app so that the absence of the database related gems does not interfere with running it. The problem is that I still want to create models using the commend `rails generate mode MyModel`. 
Under this configuration, the above command does nothing at all.
I am assuming here I would need to require some modules (for example, activemodel, which seems to provide ActiveRecord-like capabilities without necessarily having a DB) in application.rb, but I can seem to find which.
Could someone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [How to create custom generators for my rails app](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html).
Basically you will have to change the behavior of your model generators. This way you can tell which file will be created, with which code template and etc.