# ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified - database is not configured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ibm-cloud

I have started getting this error when pushing my Ruby on Rails app to Bluemix. My app doesn't actually need a database, but I have the following in `database.yml`:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

And in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3' # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

group :production do
    gem 'rails_serve_static_assets'
end
```

These are the errors I get:

```
Could not detect rake tasks
ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app with no environment variables present
and using the production group of your Gemfile.
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:285: warning: circular argument reference - now
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a string to ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection for a configuration lookup is deprecated, please pass a symbol (:"") instead. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/staged/app/Rakefile:6)
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: '' database is not configured. Available: ["production"]
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:257:in `resolve_symbol_connection'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:240:in `resolve_string_connection'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:267:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:228:in `resolve_connection'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:152:in `resolve'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:164:in `block in resolve_all'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:163:in `each'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:163:in `resolve_all'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:69:in `resolve'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:46:in `configurations='
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:48:in `block in <module:Core>'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `class_eval'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `append_features'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:297:in `include'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:297:in `<class:Base>'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:282:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:39:in `require'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:39:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:237:in `instance_exec'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:237:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:245:in `each'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:245:in `each_registered_block'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:237:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:449:in `load_tasks'
/tmp/staged/app/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/tmp/staged/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
###### WARNING:
You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
ruby '2.2.3'
```

Comment: Looks to me like you're missing some config to set RAILS_ENV, it's currently an empty string I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like RAILS_ENV variable is not set. I have not used Bluemix so not sure how to export variables there. If you don't need database, you don't have to include activerecord. see following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821251/how-to-configure-ruby-on-rails-with-no-database) for more details on how to remove activerecord.